# javascript textbox_changed value

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

here is my ASPX code

```
<%@ Page Title="About Us" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site.master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="About.aspx.cs" Inherits="About" %>

<asp:Content ID="HeaderContent" runat="server" ContentPlaceHolderID="HeadContent">
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
        function sum(t1)
        {
            var txt1 = document.getElementById('MainContent_TextBox2').value;
            var result = parseInt(txt1) / 2;
            var result1 = parseInt(result);
            if (!isNaN(result))
            {
                document.getElementById(t1).value = result1;
            }
        }
</script>
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="BodyContent" runat="server" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent">
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" runat="server" onkeyup="sum('MainContent_TextBox3')"</asp:TextBox>
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox3" runat="server" ReadOnly="True"></asp:TextBox>
<br />
<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" onclick="Button1_Click"/>
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox4" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
```

and my c# code is that

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

public partial class About : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        TextBox4.Text = TextBox3.Text;
    }
}
```

the problem is that when i click on Button1 no error and TextBox4 is empty and i want that when i click on Button1 textbox3 value is transfered in textbox4.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because of the `ReadOnly="True"` that you have set on `TextBox3`.

When a control is set to `ReadOnly` in ASP.NET, the value that was placed into the control when the page was original rendered will not be updated.

Even if you change the value in the control on the browser (as you are doing), the value that is sent back to the server will not effect the value in the TextBox control - it will keep it's old value thanks to the `ViewState`.

The answer is to store the new value in a `<asp:HiddenField>`, which you should update at the same time as `TextBox3`.

Then on the server use the value in the hidden field, as that will contain the value you want.  (Also, remember that you will need to update the value in the textbox from the hidden control as part of the postback).